# What is the difference between "hurry" and "rush"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms, speech

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English in a [THESAURUS section for "hurry"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hurry) defines/compares "hurry" and "rush" as follows:

**hurry:** to go somewhere or do something more quickly than usual, for example because you are late or you must finish something soon

1. If you don’t hurry, you’ll miss the bus.
2. We have plenty of time. There’s no need to hurry.

**rush:** to go somewhere very quickly, or to do something too quickly and without thinking carefully enough

1. Everyone rushed out into the street to see what was happening.
2. Try to answer the questions calmly, without rushing.
3. A police car rushed past.

In a [THESAURUS section for "rush"](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rush) it defines/compares "hurry" and "rush" as follows:

**rush:** to move very quickly, especially because you need to be somewhere soon

1. He was rushing out of his office in order to go to a meeting.
2. There’s no need to rush - we have plenty of time.

**hurry:** to do something or go somewhere more quickly than usual, especially because there is not much time

1. People hurried into stores to escape the rain.
2. You ll have to hurry or we 'll be late for breakfast
3. I hurried through the rest of my workout and showered as quickly as I could.

Actually, I don't get the point! It seems that they can be used interchangeably. If it is not the case, then when should I use *hurry* and when should I use *rush*?

Comment: In my experience, *rush* carries the implication of speeding up action to the point of sloppiness, where *hurry* does not.

Comment: There is no relevant difference, as your dictionary and'/or search engine should have told you.

There might be slight differences of emphasis, but not worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1984) puts *hurry* as a verb and *rush* as a verb in separate synonym clusters. *Hurry* appears in a group with *speed*, *accelerate*, *quicken*, *hasten*, and *precipitate*:

> **Speed, accelerate, quicken, hasten, hurry, precipitate** can mean to go or make go fast or faster. ... **Hurry** implies haste that causes confusion or prevents concentrated attention {his aim was *hurried* and his shot went wide of the mark} {a second fear ... which madly *hurries* her she knows not whither—*Shak*.} {these defects might pass more easily in a turbulent romanticist, *hurrying* pell-mell to get expressed some moving and dramatic scene, careless of details—*Fry*}

Meanwhile, *rush* appears in a group with *dash*, *tear*, *shoot*, and *charge*:

> **rush, dash, tear, shoot, charge** can all mean to move or cause to move forward with speed. **Rush** suggests either impetuosity or intense hurry on account of some exigency, and often carelessness about the concomitant effects of the precipitate action {*rush* for a train} {*rush* a research paper into print} { flying rout of suns and galaxies, *rushing* away from the solar system—*Forster*} {business *rushed* forward into the glittering years—*Amer. Guide Series: Ind.*}

Because MW doesn't compare *hurry* and *rush* side by side, the only suggestion of difference I can glean from the parallel discussions of the two terms is the idea that *rush* represents an intensified form of *hurry*. But this inference arises only obliquely, and ultimately the Merriam-Webster treatment of the two terms isn't terribly useful. I note, too, that the predecessor to this dictionary, *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942), provided no coverage of *rush* at all. This omission might point to increased use of *rush* in the sense of "hurry" in the decades since 1942, or it might indicate a rather scattershot approach to identifying and distinguishing between synonyms in that earlier volume. But even the newer *MW Dictionary of Synonyms* is only marginally helpful in clarifying how *hurry* and *rush* differ.

A more direct comparison of *hurry* and *rush* as verbs appears in S.I. Hayakawa, *Modern Guide to Synonyms and Related Words* (1968), which bundles both words in a group of synonyms that also includes *quicken*, *accelerate*, *expedite*, *hasten*, and *speed*:

> **quicken, accelerate, expedite, hasten, hurry, rush, speed** These words mean to move or cause to move faster. ... **Hurry** and **rush** are similar to *hasten*, but suggest in addition precipitous or confused motion. {The late arrivals were *hurried* to their seats; The stricken man was *rushed* to a hospital.} *Rush* suggests greater urgency than *hurry*, and sometimes includes the notion of violent action: They suddenly *rushed* pell-mell out the door.

I think that the distinction in Hayakawa's examples between "*hurried* to their seats" and "*rushed* to a hospital" does a good job of distinguishing between the degrees of urgency that (often) are involved in actual usage of the two terms. It's not that no one would ever say "they were rushed to their seats" or "he was hurried to a hospital"—but the word choices that Hayakawa cites strike the right level of intensity for the contexts in which they appear. His view that *rush* typically implies greater urgency or even violence than *hurry* is, I think, correct more often than not.

Comment: A person who is hurrying may still attempt to attend to decorum and other matters. A person who is rushing has abandoned such niceties.